# How to set selection at "holding" state in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Markdown preview area, after click text in preview, preview area will switch to markdown source editor, and caret auto jump to the position corresponding to before click.

```
function onMouseDown(e) {
  const range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  const position = markdownSourcePosition(source, range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
  switchToEditorAndSetCaretToPosition(position)
}
```

When single click, this work fine. but if I hold mouse button and try to select, after switch to editor, can't maintain selection state, caret stop original clicked position.

Is there any method to set selection state to "now selecting" and not finish selection until release mouse button?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but you could use the appropriate `window.getSelection` function to audit whether the user is currently selecting and not clicking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

For instance:

```
!!getSelection().toString()
//  === true if user has a selection and false otherwise
```

This way you can test if he's selecting and prevent default behavior if he is:

```
if (!getSelection().toString()) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use `contenteditable` with `selectionchange` solve this problem

on `selectionchange` triggered, use `getSelection` get focus and anchor, transform position to position in the markdown source and select on source.